# Choosing the correct statistical test, continues dependent variable measured in different time points

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression

I would like to know the correct method to analyse my data.

I did an interventional study on the effect of increased energy expenditure on appetite sensations.

The independent variable: Energy expenditure (quantitative).
The dependent variable: Visual Analogue Scores (VAS) of appetite (quantitative). (5 appetite sensations: hunger, satiety, fullness, desire to eat, prospective consumption). I plan to analyse every sensation individually, i.e.

hunger= b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + .... + bixi

I would like to adjust for age, gender, and other categorical variables.

I only have one group of participants and the VAS was measured in 5 time points (twice before the intervention and three times during the intervention).

I hypothesised that "The increase of energy expenditure increases the scores of hunger, desire to eat and prospective consumption, while it decreases the scores of satiety and fullness in a middle-aged population".
I also want to split the group by gender to know if the effect is different between men and women.

The research questions are:

- Does the increase of energy expenditure increase the score of hunger, desire to eat, and prospective consumption in a middle-aged population?
- Does the increase of energy expenditure decrease the score of satiety and fullness in a middle-aged population?

I proposed to use linear mixed model to answer the RQs, but I would like to know whither this method is correct or I should use another method?